# Android Studio - Upgrading to Java 7

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I have the following snippet to put into my `build.gradle` file to use Java 7, but I have 3 seperate `build.gradle` files and I'm unsure which one to use.

The 3 are listed below

1) Project: project name
2) Module Library
3) Module Sample

**Snippet to put in build.gradle**

```
android {
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Android Studio's own settings GUI (as of v1.1.0 : `File` menu / `Project Structure` / my_app / `Properties` tab) the snippet is added to the module's `build.gradle`, not the global one. So I guess this is right place.